# How to check in PHP 5.4 if an access path exists in a multidimensional JSON array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I want to access elements in an array generated by json_encode and want to be sure the element exists. To suppress a warning if it does not exist I use a @ prior:

1) When access path in array exists all works as expected

```
$test = @$obj['tag']    
// result is "ABCD" if "ABCD" set, "" if "" and NULL if NULL => as
```

expected

2) When access path in array only partial exists Strings cause a problem

```
$test = @$obj['tag']['dddd'] 
// = "A" when ['tag'] = "ABCD", I understand that 'dddd' becomes an index of 0 in the array representing the string.
```

Any way to avoid this?

Comment: You Sir are looking for `isset()`.

Comment: If it's unknown whether an element is a string or an array, you need to involve an explicit test with `is_array` somewhere.

Comment: As long as you are not expecting a 0 in your value, you can also use the `empty` keyword, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php - I put an example on an online PHP sandbox here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a91b31239e357c348acbebe0cf39f75a7853ca1c

Comment: @Dan: Nope - unfortunately, does isset() not do the job! Tried it out before. :@deceze: Right but then need to program it explicit. Had no luck with varable variable either.@Shaun: Sounds like a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out isset / is_scalar / is_null / empty I came to the followig conclusion for multidimensional arrays generated out of JSON data:

1) isset() does not distinguish between the value "null" with an existing key and a not existing key (I used @ for the access path to suppress warnings). "" strings are handled fine.

2) There is one anomaly if an access path contains a string. In this case the first character of the string will be the result. It does not matter how many dimensions come after the string. Will always reference the 0 index of the string array.

To avoid any problems I do now:
1) Use no null in JSON, what is a good idea anyway.
2) Avoid strings with a single char. If needed instead of Y/N using a boolean true/false could be used.

### Test data:

`isset is_scalar is_null empty access path                  value`
`TRUE  TRUE      FALSE   FALSE @$obj['tag']['dddd']['wwww'] A (not existing)`
`TRUE  TRUE      FALSE   FALSE @$obj['tag']['dddd']         A (not existing)`
`TRUE  TRUE      FALSE   FALSE @$obj['tag']                 ABCD`
`TRUE  TRUE      FALSE   FALSE @$obj['tagf']                ABCD`
`TRUE  TRUE      FALSE   FALSE @$obj['user']['name']        Broemm`
`TRUE  TRUE      FALSE   FALSE @$obj['user']['num']         1234`
`FALSE FALSE     TRUE    TRUE  @$obj['user']['num']['dddd’] (not existing)`
`TRUE  TRUE      FALSE   TRUE  @$obj['time']['b']['b’]      “"`
`FALSE FALSE     TRUE    TRUE  @$obj['time']['c']['b’]      null`
`FALSE FALSE     TRUE    TRUE  @$obj['tttt’]                (not existing)`
`TRUE  TRUE      FALSE   FALSE @$obj['boo']                 1`
`FALSE FALSE     TRUE    TRUE  @$obj['boo']['qq']           (not existing)`
`FALSE FALSE     TRUE    TRUE  @$obj['boo']['qq']['ee’]     (not existing)`